# Python Cannot create a file error [Error : 183]

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

I am using the following code to copy the contents of one directory to another directory (python)

```
shutil.copytree(sourceDirectory,destinationDirectory,symlinks=False,ignore=ignore_patterns(updatedList))
```

where

> updatedList = ,*.config,*.ico,*.log

I am generating this updatedList on the fly (based on user inputs) 
However I keep getting the following error whenever I try to perform the copy operation as stated above.

> [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

**Note : There will be some files that are present in the source directory matching the extensions mentioned in the updatedList.**

I am thinking that mentioning the extension of the files that are already present in the ignore list should suffice, but apparently it does not.

I am currently using Python 2.7

My Imports

```
import logging
import os
from win32api import GetFileVersionInfo, LOWORD, HIWORD
import zipfile
import shutil
import sys
from os.path import isfile
from distutils import dir_util
import ConfigDTO
import datetime
import UpdateSettings
import time
import win32api
import socket
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns
import os
```

Please help .

Thanks

Comment: What is `updatedList` really defined as? The example you have there is invalid syntax.

Comment: It might also help if you show your `import` statements.

Comment: @bernie , updatedList is defined as thus : updatedList = ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it .. sorry it was my mistake. The document for shutil specifically says that the destination directory must not exist. well in  my case , the destination directory was existing earlier and hence i was getting the message.

Thanks

[more information here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)